# Freemarker does not assign staticUtil

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7, display-templates

I worked Application Display Templates on liferay 6.2, I use freemarker help pagination the dynamics data list of liferay. When I upgrade to liferay 7, it is a problem. Liferay 7 use code `<#assign records = ddlDisplayTemplateHelper.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id)>` for get a records.

Old code:

> `<#assign DDLRecordLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordLocalService")>
>   <#assign records = DDLRecordLocalService.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id)>
>   <#assign totalRecord = DDLRecordLocalService.getRecordsCount(reserved_record_set_id, 0) >`

It doesn't work.

So I try `<#assign serviceLocator = staticUtil["com.liferay.portal.template.ServiceLocator"]>` but `staticUtil` get an error.

> The following has evaluated to null or missing:
>   ==> staticUtil  [in template "20115#20159#21387" at line 9, column 27]
>   Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing

In portal-ext.properties I have added:

```
freemarker.engine.restricted.classes=
freemarker.engine.restricted.packages=
freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=
```

Answer (score 7):

The properties you refer to have been moved to an OSGI config in Liferay 7/DXP. 
To deploy them you need to create a file named **com.liferay.portal.template.freemarker.configuration.FreeMarkerEngineConfiguration.cfg** and place it under `$LIFERAY_HOME/osgi/configs`

The content of the file will be the following:

```
restrictedVariables=
```

To find all the configs and their defaults you can have a look at the class `com.liferay.portal.template.freemarker.configuration.FreeMarkerEngineConfiguration`

That you can find in the Liferay source code.

Comment: it does not seem to work in my local environment. I did exactly as you said. Do you know if this is already deprecated?

Comment: This is the correct procedure for LR 7, but just as an increment here, you might fine tune to use what you need leaving other restrictions... 
restrictedVariables=["","utilLocator","objectUtil","staticFieldGetter","staticUtil"]

Answer (score 5):

I think those properties in portal-ext.properties are just ignored in liferay 7.

You can admin those properties in Control Panel → Configuration → System Settings → Foundation → FreeMarker Engine and remove "staticUtil" (or remove "serviceLocator" directly) from restricted variables. (liferay reboot is required)

Comment: They are not ignored, they have been moved into OSGI config files. Depending on the version and service pack I've experienced that updating them from the control panel may cause the Liferay instance to brake (not startup anymore) so I strongly discourage doing that

Comment: I've also had Liferay DXP break when updating those values from the control panel. You have to do some database Foo to get LR to boot again. I'll upvote you above.

Comment: For anyone who has problems with LR booting this is what I did to get LR starting again: https://youtu.be/Aot3oRP7hDg

Comment: @Totò I have tried creating a file com.liferay.portal.template.freemarker.configuration.FreeMarkerEngineConfiguration.cfg in osgi folder as metioned in the answer below, but it does not seem to have an effect. Do you know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

- Go to Control Panel -> System Settings -> Foundation Page
- Find **FreeMarker Engine**  from list click on it .
- Remove **serviceLocator** variable and **staticUtil** from restricted variables by Clicking on (-) icon.
- If you want to use **staticUtil** object then also remove this variable from restricted variables.
- Save it.
- Restart Liferay server.

You will direct access to serviceLocator object in your Application Display Template.

Answer (score 2):

In liferay 7.1. you will find Freemaker Engine under

> Control Panel -> System Settings -> Platform -> Template Engines

Answer (score 1):

In liferay-ce-portal-7.1.1.2-ga3 version, the file is renamed to

```
com.liferay.portal.template.freemarker.configuration.FreeMarkerEngineConfiguration.config
```